# Tried sum multiple sums

Tags: mysql, sum

I tried to sum multiple sums like this:

```
    SELECT
    `users`.*,
    @attackPower := FLOOR(SUM(IF( `weapons`.`weaponeType` = 'atk',`weapons`.`weaponPower` * `weapons_has_users`.`count` , 0 ) )) AS `attackPower` ,
    @defencePower := FLOOR(SUM(IF( `weapons`.`weaponeType` = 'def', `weapons`.`weaponPower` * `weapons_has_users`.`count` , 0 ) )) AS `defencePower`,
    @spyPower := FLOOR(SUM(IF( `weapons`.`weaponeType` = 'spy', `weapons`.`weaponPower` * `weapons_has_users`.`count` , 0 ) )) AS `spyPower`,
    @uniPower := FLOOR(SUM(IF( `weapons`.`weaponeType` = 'uni', `weapons`.`weaponPower` * `weapons_has_users`.`count` , 0 ) )) AS `uniPower`,
    (@attackPower + @defencePower + @spyPower + @uniPower) as `power`

    FROM `users`
    LEFT JOIN `weapons_has_users` ON `users`.`userId` = `weapons_has_users`.`userId`
    LEFT JOIN `weapons` ON `weapons`.`weaponId` = `weapons_has_users`.`weaponId`
```

But `power` returns NULL
what I can to do to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL documentation *specifically* warns against assigning and using variables in the same statement.

In addition, you need a subquery if you are going to use aggregation functions in the query (and you want more than one row returned).

Because you need to use aggregation, you might as well use a subquery:

```
select u.*,
    (attackPower + defencePower + spyPower + uniPower) as `power`
from (SELECT `users`.*,
             FLOOR(SUM(IF( `weapons`.`weaponeType` = 'atk',`weapons`.`weaponPower` * `weapons_has_users`.`count` , 0 ) )) AS `attackPower` ,
             FLOOR(SUM(IF( `weapons`.`weaponeType` = 'def', `weapons`.`weaponPower` * `weapons_has_users`.`count` , 0 ) )) AS `defencePower`,
             FLOOR(SUM(IF( `weapons`.`weaponeType` = 'spy', `weapons`.`weaponPower` * `weapons_has_users`.`count` , 0 ) )) AS `spyPower`,
             FLOOR(SUM(IF( `weapons`.`weaponeType` = 'uni', `weapons`.`weaponPower` * `weapons_has_users`.`count` , 0 ) )) AS `uniPower`,

      FROM `users` LEFT JOIN
           `weapons_has_users`
           ON `users`.`userId` = `weapons_has_users`.`userId` LEFT JOIN
           `weapons`
           ON `weapons`.`weaponId` = `weapons_has_users`.`weaponId`
      GROUP BY users.id
    ) u;
```